# How to add text panes and labels

Tags: java, forms, swing, jframe

I've tried to create a JFrame windows form with a label and a text pane in that order, vertically down the form as opposed to beside one another.

Any code I've tried does not work, instead just loading the form and nothing else.

Keep in mind I'm opening this JFrame from another JFrame, pressing a JButton in order to open this "form".

```
    JLabel l1, l2;
    JTextField t1, t2;
    
    public DialogueBoxes(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Gameplay Boxes");
        
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        c.add(l1);
        c.add(t1);
        c.add(l2);
        c.add(t2);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that "doesn't work."  It's much easier to help you if we can see what you are trying to do.  A [mcve] is practically required most of the time.

Comment: apologies. Please see the code above.

Comment: your gridlayout has only 1 row and 1 column which mean it hold single element so either update the number of row or column within the constructor or use 0 for row to get max row or use 0 for column to get max column as mentioned here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html

Comment: another point you setdefaultclose to exit only when you need to close the app but since this is a dialog or internal frame then use one of those constant WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE","WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE","WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial shows how to use GridLayout.

```
GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,2);
```

The text says:

> Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the layout are given equal size. One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero, which means that any number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.

So if you want a "flexible" layout then use a zero for the rows or the columns (but not for both) so you can add as many components as you'd like.  The example I showed above has two columns and a flexible number of rows.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html